# Custom image assets for use in the App Store

Tags: ios, app-store, customization, assets

In the iOS App Store, some apps are presented in a custom and non standard way.

Instead of a standard app icon and standard black text describing the app, some apps in the App Store feature a custom background color scheme and custom banner at the top of the screen.

In the below example, an image is used in the banner, along with a dark red background and white buttons and text.

> **Question:**
>
> How can customization be achieved in Xcode and Swift code for images that
>   will appear in the App Store? Precisely what corresponding Image
>   Assets need to be prepared in Xcode?

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: This is only available for featured apps. Probably something you would need to talk to Apple about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is special functionality that is only available to apps Apple wants to highlight. If/when your app qualifies, they will contact you regarding asset submission.